# Looker Studio - Using CASE to Define Segment Based on Page Path Question

Tags: google-analytics, case, looker-studio

Since Google only samples a small portion of demographic traffic, I want to use a CASE statement in a Custom Definition to define traffic based on page path. This would be used as a drop down list control.

I've built the CASE function, but I'm getting results that don't seem to match the expected numbers.

For example.

Total User might be 100k for a week, but the CASE statement might say US is 150k, Canada is 40k and Australia is 30k. This is much greater than the 100k of total traffic.

And then when I select the US for the drop down, my total users goes from 100k to 150k.

It's very confusing.

I created the following CASE statement to capture the each country's homepage and subsequent pages. I've verified its capturing the page paths as expected.

```
CASE 
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path, "/en/") OR Page Path = ("/en") THEN "US" 
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path, "/en-ca/") OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path, "/en-CA/") OR Page Path = ("/en-ca") OR Page Path = ("/en-CA") THEN "CA" 
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path, "/en-au/") OR CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path, "/en-AU/") OR Page Path = ("/en-au") OR Page Path = ("/en-AU") THEN "AU" 
ELSE "Other" 
END
```

Here are the results for all paid media for the previous week.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZM64.jpg)

The CASE is overstating by almost double.